# for in loop weird behavior

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop, lexical-scope

I've got some weird behavior with a for-in loop.

**Code:**

```
var obj = {
    q:1,
    w:2,
    e:4,
    r:5
};

function test(data) {
    for (key in data) {
        //do sth;
    }
}

!function() {
    for (key in obj) {
        console.log(key);
        test({a:1,b:2,c:3});
        console.log(key);
    }
}();
```

as i expected the output should be sth like this:

q q w w e e r r

but i got this:

q c w c e c r c

i can't find the logic behind this behavior!
the key variables are scoped lexically !
what's worng with my code?

Comment: Remember to `let` or `var` any identifiers at the level you want them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `key` with `var` in both functions. Currently, it's an implicit global variable.

```
function test(data){
    for (var key in data){
        //do sth;
    }
}
```

Because it's global, references to `key` in both function involve the same variable, so the loop in `test()` messes up the loop in the anonymous function.

(You could use `let` instead of `var` if you wanted to, though in this case it would make no difference.)